# Using what to create cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

Wherever I look this is the correct way to add a Cookie:

```
HttpCookie Session = new HttpCookie("Session");
Session.Value = someguid;
Session.Expires = somedatetime;

Response.Cookies.Add(Session);
```

And wherever there is no explanation as to how to get Response into the current context. So I get this error:

```
The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context
```

What do I need to do to get the above code to work?

Comment: Where are you putting this code? Can you provide some context?

Comment: @Cory: It's inside a class function and the class is just a simple class I made. No inheritance. Do this somehow have to be inside the controller class? o_O

Comment: How do you use the class? Do you create an instance of it inside your controller?

Comment: @Core: Yes, inside my controller class I do create a new instance of the class.

Comment: I just tried to move the cookie creating code to my controller class and now it works. Simple solution to this is that is has to be inside the controller class.

Comment: Or you have to pass the `Response` object to your helper class so you can use it outside of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response` if you sure that this code will be executed inside web application.
But I have life-proven practice (and Law of Demeter says the same) to pass Response as a parameter to a method where I want to use it.